# C# csvhelper writing separate rows

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I'm using CSVHelper to read and write to a csv file from my datagridview.

I can read a csv file however when I write it lists the headers and the rows on the same row.

How do I make the rows go in separate rows in excel?

```
private void btnWrite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog() {  Filter = "CSV|*.csv", ValidateNames = true })
    {
        if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(sfd.FileName))
            {
                var csvwriter = new CsvWriter(sw, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                csvwriter.WriteHeader(typeof(Student));

                foreach (Student s in studentBindingSource.DataSource as List<Student>)
                {
                    csvwriter.WriteRecord(s);
                    csvwriter.Flush();
                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Data has been saved", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
        }
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

Comment: Please refer to the library you are using as CSVHelper.

Comment: @RezaNoei the one called [CSVHelper](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are manually writing individual records (`WriteRecord` rather than `WriteRecords`), or manually writing the header (`WriteHeader`), then you need to manually go to the next record.

```
var csvwriter = new CsvWriter(sw, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
csvwriter.WriteHeader(typeof(Student));
csvwriter.NextRecord(); // < ---- this

foreach (Student s in studentBindingSource.DataSource as List<Student>)
{
    csvwriter.WriteRecord(s);
    csvwriter.NextRecord(); // < ---- this
}
```

Read more at [CSVHelper's documentation page](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/#writing-a-csv-file).

> WriteHeader will not advance you to the next row. Separating NextRecord from WriteHeader allows you to write more things in the header if you need to. WriteRecord also will not advance you to the next row to give you the ability to write multiple objects or use WriteField to write individual fields.

---

Side note, I'd recommend you add a `using` block/statement to the `csvwriter` variable, so that it will flush automatically and correctly.

Comment: @RezaNoei As you showed in your answer the task with this library can be as simple as `csvwriter.WriteRecords(records)`.  When writing manually, `csvwriter.NextRecord()` does seem more complex than it needs to be, but it was done to give the user more flexibility.  You could, for instance, add your own columns after the header before going to the data lines. `csvwriter.WriteHeader<Student>(); csvwriter.WriteField("MyExtraField"); csvwriter.NextRecord();` You can do the same thing on the data lines.

Comment: I had several experiments with unexpected results. I'm talking about `Encapsulation` you want to write a csv file ? Simply use `String.Join` method, not a complicated Third-Party. If you want to add magics `Clarify in ///<Summary>`

Comment: You want to add extra fields ? Use linq `.Select` and map your new property, As simple as possible.

Comment: You can simply use `String.Join` until you end up with either a comma, a line break, or a double quote in your data. And this may not matter to you, but `CsvHelper` has been designed to be faster than `String.Join`. I personally like it for reading CSV. I use it to dynamically match up column headers to my classes.

Answer (score 1):

```
 private void btnWrite_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     using (SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog() { Filter = "CSV|*.csv", ValidateNames = true })
     {
         if (sfd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
         {
             using (var sw = new StreamWriter(sfd.FileName))
             {
                 var csvwriter = new CsvWriter(sw, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
                 csvwriter.WriteRecords<Student>(studentBindingSource.DataSource as List<Student>);
             }
 
             MessageBox.Show("Data has been saved", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
         }
     }
 }
```